# Plot points and polygon matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot a point, a circle surrounding a point with a given radius and polygons from array of coods as input. I have the following code implemented

```
    plot(start(1),start(2))
    axis([0,256,0,256]);
    hold on;
    %pdecirc(endp(1),endp(2),10);
    for i = 1:size(X,1)
           patch(X(i),Y(i),'r');
    end
```

However, pdecirc is not working. it opens a new editor and thus I have commented it. X and Y are 2d arrays of dimensions (no.of points X 4). Thus X(i) has 4 X values and Y(i) has 4 X values. This code is not drawing the polygons as expected. Can you please tell me the best way of achieving what am trying to do? A code would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that pdecirc is part of a matlab pde toolkit, not for generic circle drawing, here's something quick

```
r     = 10;
theta = linspace(0, 2 * pi, 100);
x     = r * cos(theta);
y     = r * sin(theta);
plot(x, y);
```

does your patch command work?

Comment: do you see an error message, or is it drawing something funny? if drawing something funny, can you give a quick example of what the data looks like? Could your data point be out of the 0/256 x/y limits? in the current setup, it should draw 4 polygons

Comment: are you pointing out to my command without the circle? is it drawing for you? please provide me the sample data used. No, there's no error message. Just the polygon missing. and the plot blank

Comment: i think you are missing some :. do `patch(X(:, i), Y(:, i), 'r')`. In fact you don't need the for loop at all, you can just do `patch(X, Y, 'r')`

Comment: Thank you. Just patch did it :).